# Casting to an abstract class

Tags: class, methods, call, abstract

Alright, so I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Animal {
   public abstract String sound();
}
```

So, then I have a class that extends it:

```
public class Chicken extends Animal {
   public String sound() {
      return "Cockadoodledoo!";
   }
}
```

Then say I have a test class with a main method:

```
public class Test {
   Chicken a = new Chicken();
   System.out.println((Animal)a).sound());
}
```

The output is "Cockadoodledoo!" So my question is why, if I caste a to Animal, does it still call the method in Chicken? Wouldn't it see a as an object of Animal? Is it because sound() is abstract so it can't be called.. but then wouldn't it give me an exception?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's overloaded. you should expect this. basically you won't be able to call `sound` in `Animal` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The object created in memory is still an instance of the `Chicken` class.  What you are doing by casting is treating it as if it were an instance of the `Animal` class, meaning you can only use methods and properties available to that class.

So if your `Chicken` class had a `LayEgg()` method, for instance, casting it to an `Animal` would mean that you are unable to call that method (unless you cast back, because it is still a `Chicken` in the machine's memory).  You can still call the methods available to `Animal`, and the behaviour will be that of the actual object that was instantiated.

It's exactly the same as going:

```
Animal myAnimal = new Chicken();
```

Comment: The technical term you're looking for here is 'late binding'.